# $2x = 2y \Rightarrow x = y$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory

How can I show, $2x = 2y \Rightarrow x = y$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$, when I can only use elements out of $\mathbb{Z}$? It is $\frac{1}{2} \notin \mathbb{Z}$, so I can't multiply both sides with $\frac{1}{2}$. How can I prove it?

Comment: Can you prove that the function $f(x) = 2x$ is strictly increasing?

Comment: Even though $\frac12\notin \Bbb Z$, you can divide _even_ numbers by $2$. Or, rather, you can cancel the multiplication by $2$ in your equation.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
2x&=2y
\\ \Rightarrow2x-2y&=0
\\ \Rightarrow 2(x-y)&=0
\\ \Rightarrow 2=0&\text{ or }x-y=0
\\ \Rightarrow x&=y.
\end{align}$$

**EDIT:** This (or rather I) implicitly uses the field axioms of $\mathbb{Q}$. We need [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57627/proof-that-mathbbz-has-no-zero-divisors) to fix it.

**EDIT 2** How about this:
$$\begin{align}
2x&=2y
\\\Rightarrow x+x&=y+y
\\\Rightarrow x-y&=-(x-y)
\end{align}
$$
The only number that is its own inverse is zero. Hence $x=y$.

Comment: Your first solution works just fine since $\mathbb Z$ is an (rather, 'the') integral domain so there are no nonzero zero divisors.

Answer (score 2):

$$2x=2y \Leftrightarrow 2x-2y=0 \Leftrightarrow 2(x-y)=0$$